# sum of infinite series

Tags: infinite-sequences

Given the complex variable $x$, complex constant $c$, and integer number $r$. I want to solve the equation:
$\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{e^{kx}}{k^r}=c$. I was thinking that if there is a formula or special function that can simplify the left side of the equation, then I may be able to find the analytical solution of $x$. So my question is: is there any formula for the sum of infinite series in the form of $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{e^{kx}}{k}$ or $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{e^{kx}}{k^2}$?

Comment: If you don't have to be rigorous just take the derivatives until you get a geometric series.

Answer (score 3):

According to Mathematica,
$$\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{e^{k x}}{k^r} = Li_r(e^x),$$
which is not much of a revelation since $Li$ is the *polylogarithm* function, defined as
$$Li_n(z) =\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{z^k}{k^n}.$$
But at least you know now that it is the [polylogarithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polylogarithm) that you are looking for. Wikipedia seems to have a decent description of it.

Comment: Given the popular inverse function of the logarithm, you would think the polylog's inverse would have a name (the polyexp?)

Answer (score 2):

Where did you look?  What did you try?
$$
\sum_{k = 1}^{\infty} \frac{\operatorname{e} ^{k x}}{k} = -\operatorname{ln} \bigl(1 - \operatorname{e} ^{x}\bigr)
$$
(the derivative is a geometric series, whose sum is known.)